# Can't install uWSGI on M1 macOS using pip

Tags: python, macos, uwsgi, apple-m1

I tried installing uwsgi with `pip install uwsgi`. This worked in macOS Big Sur (11), but now in Monterey (12) it fails.

Here is the output (saee is my username):

```
❯ pip install uwsgi
Collecting uwsgi
  Using cached uwsgi-2.0.20.tar.gz (804 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: uwsgi
  Building wheel for uwsgi (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/saee/Desktop/as/shell/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jq/ynjgrhqx2gz7sfd1tnwft4g00000gn/T/pip-install-78t_g24b/uwsgi_3c29c5a278804046979cb1319ade3427/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jq/ynjgrhqx2gz7sfd1tnwft4g00000gn/T/pip-install-78t_g24b/uwsgi_3c29c5a278804046979cb1319ade3427/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/jq/ynjgrhqx2gz7sfd1tnwft4g00000gn/T/pip-wheel-a41p4rbp
       cwd: /private/var/folders/jq/ynjgrhqx2gz7sfd1tnwft4g00000gn/T/pip-install-78t_g24b/uwsgi_3c29c5a278804046979cb1319ade3427/
  Complete output (180 lines):
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  copying uwsgidecorators.py -> build/lib
  installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  using profile: buildconf/default.ini
  detected include path: ['/usr/local/include', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks']
  Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
  detected CPU cores: 8
  configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_OSX_SPINLOCK -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_KQUEUE -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre/8.45/include -DUWSGI_PCRE -DUWSGI_ROUTING -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.20\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="20" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/yajl/2.1.0/include/ -DUWSGI_JSON -DUWSGI_JSON_YAJL -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_EXPAT -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
  *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
  [thread 0][clang] core/utils.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/protocol.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/socket.o
  ...
  [thread 0][clang] core/dot_h.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/config_py.o
  *** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/python/python_plugin.o
  [thread 4][clang] plugins/python/pyutils.o
  [thread 5][clang] plugins/python/pyloader.o
  [thread 7][clang] plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o
  ...
  [thread 5][clang] plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o
  [thread 7][clang] plugins/transformation_template/tt.o
  [thread 6][clang] plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o
  *** uWSGI linking ***
  clang -o build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/wheel/uWSGI-2.0.20.data/scripts/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o core/zlib.o core/regexp.o core/routing.o core/yaml.o core/json.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/python/raw.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o plugins/transformation_template/tt.o plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o -lpthread -lm -lz -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre/8.45/lib -lpcre -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/yajl/2.1.0/lib -lyajl -lexpat -ldl -framework CoreFoundation /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin/libpython3.9.a
  ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre/8.45/lib/libpcre.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
  ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/yajl/2.1.0/lib/libyajl.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_pcre_compile", referenced from:
        _uwsgi_regexp_build in regexp.o
    "_pcre_config", referenced from:
        _uwsgi_opt_pcre_jit in regexp.o
    "_pcre_exec", referenced from:
        _uwsgi_regexp_match in regexp.o
        _uwsgi_regexp_match_ovec in regexp.o
    "_pcre_free", referenced from:
        _uwsgi_regexp_build in regexp.o
        _uwsgi_route_condition_regexp in routing.o
    "_pcre_free_study", referenced from:
        _uwsgi_route_condition_regexp in routing.o
    "_pcre_fullinfo", referenced from:
        _uwsgi_regexp_ovector in regexp.o
    "_pcre_study", referenced from:
        _uwsgi_regexp_build in regexp.o
    "_yajl_tree_get", referenced from:
        _uwsgi_json_config in json.o
    "_yajl_tree_parse", referenced from:
        _uwsgi_json_config in json.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  *** error linking uWSGI ***
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for uwsgi
  Running setup.py clean for uwsgi
Failed to build uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
    Running setup.py install for uwsgi ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/saee/Desktop/as/shell/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jq/ynjgrhqx2gz7sfd1tnwft4g00000gn/T/pip-install-78t_g24b/uwsgi_3c29c5a278804046979cb1319ade3427/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jq/ynjgrhqx2gz7sfd1tnwft4g00000gn/T/pip-install-78t_g24b/uwsgi_3c29c5a278804046979cb1319ade3427/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jq/ynjgrhqx2gz7sfd1tnwft4g00000gn/T/pip-record-3o3j1kg1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/saee/Desktop/as/shell/include/site/python3.9/uwsgi
         cwd: /private/var/folders/jq/ynjgrhqx2gz7sfd1tnwft4g00000gn/T/pip-install-78t_g24b/uwsgi_3c29c5a278804046979cb1319ade3427/
    Complete output (173 lines):
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    using profile: buildconf/default.ini
    detected include path: ['/usr/local/include', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks']
    Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
    detected CPU cores: 8
    configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_OSX_SPINLOCK -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_KQUEUE -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre/8.45/include -DUWSGI_PCRE -DUWSGI_ROUTING -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.20\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="20" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/yajl/2.1.0/include/ -DUWSGI_JSON -DUWSGI_JSON_YAJL -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_EXPAT -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
    *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
    core/utils.o is up to date
    core/protocol.o is up to date
    core/socket.o is up to date
    core/logging.o is up to date
    core/master.o is up to date
    core/master_utils.o is up to date
    core/emperor.o is up to date
    core/notify.o is up to date
    core/mule.o is up to date
    core/subscription.o is up to date
    core/stats.o is up to date
    core/sendfile.o is up to date
    core/async.o is up to date
    core/master_checks.o is up to date
    core/fifo.o is up to date
    core/offload.o is up to date
    core/io.o is up to date
    core/static.o is up to date
    core/websockets.o is up to date
    core/spooler.o is up to date
    core/snmp.o is up to date
    core/exceptions.o is up to date
    core/config.o is up to date
    core/setup_utils.o is up to date
    core/clock.o is up to date
    core/init.o is up to date
    core/buffer.o is up to date
    core/reader.o is up to date
    core/writer.o is up to date
    core/alarm.o is up to date
    core/cron.o is up to date
    core/hooks.o is up to date
    core/plugins.o is up to date
    core/lock.o is up to date
    core/cache.o is up to date
    core/daemons.o is up to date
    core/errors.o is up to date
    core/hash.o is up to date
    core/master_events.o is up to date
    core/chunked.o is up to date
    core/queue.o is up to date
    core/event.o is up to date
    core/signal.o is up to date
    core/strings.o is up to date
    core/progress.o is up to date
    core/timebomb.o is up to date
    core/ini.o is up to date
    core/fsmon.o is up to date
    core/mount.o is up to date
    core/metrics.o is up to date
    core/plugins_builder.o is up to date
    core/sharedarea.o is up to date
    core/rpc.o is up to date
    core/gateway.o is up to date
    core/loop.o is up to date
    core/cookie.o is up to date
    core/querystring.o is up to date
    core/rb_timers.o is up to date
    core/transformations.o is up to date
    core/uwsgi.o is up to date
    proto/base.o is up to date
    proto/uwsgi.o is up to date
    proto/http.o is up to date
    proto/fastcgi.o is up to date
    proto/scgi.o is up to date
    proto/puwsgi.o is up to date
    core/zlib.o is up to date
    core/regexp.o is up to date
    core/routing.o is up to date
    core/yaml.o is up to date
    core/json.o is up to date
    core/xmlconf.o is up to date
    [thread 1][clang] core/dot_h.o
    [thread 2][clang] core/config_py.o
    *** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
    plugins/python/python_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/python/pyutils.o is up to date
    ...
    plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o is up to date
    *** uWSGI linking ***
    clang -o /Users/saee/Desktop/as/shell/bin/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o core/zlib.o core/regexp.o core/routing.o core/yaml.o core/json.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o ...L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre/8.45/lib -lpcre -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/yajl/2.1.0/lib -lyajl -lexpat -ldl -framework CoreFoundation /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin/libpython3.9.a
    ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre/8.45/lib/libpcre.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
    ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/yajl/2.1.0/lib/libyajl.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_pcre_compile", referenced from:
          _uwsgi_regexp_build in regexp.o
      "_pcre_config", referenced from:
          _uwsgi_opt_pcre_jit in regexp.o
      "_pcre_exec", referenced from:
          _uwsgi_regexp_match in regexp.o
          _uwsgi_regexp_match_ovec in regexp.o
      "_pcre_free", referenced from:
          _uwsgi_regexp_build in regexp.o
          _uwsgi_route_condition_regexp in routing.o
      "_pcre_free_study", referenced from:
          _uwsgi_route_condition_regexp in routing.o
      "_pcre_fullinfo", referenced from:
          _uwsgi_regexp_ovector in regexp.o
      "_pcre_study", referenced from:
          _uwsgi_regexp_build in regexp.o
      "_yajl_tree_get", referenced from:
          _uwsgi_json_config in json.o
      "_yajl_tree_parse", referenced from:
          _uwsgi_json_config in json.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    *** error linking uWSGI ***
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/saee/Desktop/as/shell/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jq/ynjgrhqx2gz7sfd1tnwft4g00000gn/T/pip-install-78t_g24b/uwsgi_3c29c5a278804046979cb1319ade3427/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jq/ynjgrhqx2gz7sfd1tnwft4g00000gn/T/pip-install-78t_g24b/uwsgi_3c29c5a278804046979cb1319ade3427/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jq/ynjgrhqx2gz7sfd1tnwft4g00000gn/T/pip-record-3o3j1kg1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/saee/Desktop/as/shell/include/site/python3.9/uwsgi Check the logs for full command output.
```

I also have gcc installed and installing uwsgi homebrew but that has a different issue.

Comment: It looks like you have an x86_64 Python, but an arm64 Homebrew hierarchy (where yajl and pcre are from).

Comment: I had a similar problem. This helped: https://debugah.com/solved-mac-install-uwsgi-error-clang-error-no-such-file-or-directory-usersstevenpycharmprojectspythonprojectvenvlibpython3-8config-3-8libpython3-8-a-17196/

Comment: Thanks, @pe.kne! That link really helped. The problem was that the proper reference directory was in the global system python but was not available in the python installed within the virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to AKX's comment, I resolved the problem.
there was a line in ~/.zprofile that exported PATH like this

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
```

and apparently this was intel based python.
So i commented that out, and installed universal python3.9 from python.org and everything got fixed.

Comment: Using the python version installed using homebrew also works fine. Mine is located at:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/bin/python3

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of potential issues involved here, but much of it boils down to changes in macOS from Catalina (10.15) to Monterey (12).

- The system path [/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253882372?answerId=257282460022#257282460022) is no longer writable by users and has been removed. You will wish to purge all references to this directory in your [startup files](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abdy).
- Since you are on Apple Silicon (M1/M2), you will need to migrate to arm homebrew by [uninstalling the Intel homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70989823) and reinstalling into /opt/homebrew.

Once you have done this, installing uwsgi should work well:

```
% ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/ /usr/local
ls: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/: No such file or directory
ls: /usr/local: No such file or directory
% uname -a
Darwin Superbook.local 21.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Mon Aug 22 20:19:52 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.140.49~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64
% /opt/homebrew/bin/pip3.10 install uwsgi
Collecting uwsgi
  Downloading uwsgi-2.0.20.tar.gz (804 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 804.9/804.9 kB 3.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: uwsgi
  Building wheel for uwsgi (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for uwsgi: filename=uWSGI-2.0.20-cp310-cp310-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl size=457231 sha256=39ff2fe0efd45fcc004c4114aba300d46aca33c215847d29ef098219ff3dd537
  Stored in directory: /Users/risner/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/06/05/96/5ee3e21875a5cab911fdbb7d8100b24fbd639c55a65b5b6ccb
Successfully built uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
Successfully installed uwsgi-2.0.20
```