# Uninstall Homebrew from /usr/local without affecting /opt/homebrew

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon

Unaware of the problems it would cause, I made the mistake of setting up my 2021 MacBook Pro by restoring from a Time Machine backup. I thought I'd got it all worked out, and have been happily running for a couple of months, but I've just discovered that I still seem to have a Homebrew installation in /usr/local, as well as the default Apple Silicon location of /opt/homebrew, and a bunch of formulae I've installed recently are in the wrong place and linked to the wrong Homebrew installation, and new won't upgrade, failing with the error `Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!`

I've removed all the offending formulae and reinstalled them in the right place, but how do I completely remove the /usr/local Homebrew installation without affecting /opt/homebrew? Is the standard uninstall script safe to run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
% sudo /bin/zsh
# arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

This should only remove the /usr/local homebrew. It reported this in my testing:

```
==> Homebrew uninstalled!
The following possible Homebrew files were not deleted:
/usr/local/Homebrew/
/usr/local/bin/
/usr/local/etc/
/usr/local/include/
/usr/local/lib/
/usr/local/microsoft/
/usr/local/opt/
/usr/local/sbin/
/usr/local/share/
/usr/local/squid/
/usr/local/var/
You may wish to remove them yourself.
```

Comment: What's the best way to go about removing the remaining Homebrew-derived files under /usr/local/*/ without doing damage otherwise?

Comment: I get the error: `arch: posix_spawnp: /bin/bash: Bad CPU type in executable` this was fixed by installing rosetta: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`